# jScrollPane not working with twitter profile feed

Tags: twitter, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I have applied the jscrollpane into two places in the page, one is the normal static content and other one is a twitter profile feed. The first one was working fine as expected till the twitter feed implemented in the page. I am getting a blank page after this. See the code below. Any help?

Head Section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">         
    $(function()
    {
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    });         
</script>
```

Body Section:

```
    <h1>Normal Content</h1>
    <div class="scroll-pane">
        <p>
            some text ...
        </p>
    </div>

    <h1>Twitter Feed</h1>           
    <div class="scroll-pane">
    <script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
    <script>
    new TWTR.Widget({
      version: 2,
      type: 'profile',
      rpp: 10,
      interval: 30000,
      width: '300',
      height: 'auto' ,
      theme: {
        shell: {
          background: '#d12a00',
          color: '#ffffff'
        },
        tweets: {
          background: '#ffffff',
          color: '#474747',
          links: '#d12a00'
        }
      },
      features: {
        scrollbar: false,
        loop: false,
        live: false,
        behavior: 'all'
      }
    }).render().setUser('rajkut').start();          
    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add on your scrollpane method this:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
                autoReinitialise: true,
                verticalDragMinHeight: 20,
                verticalDragMaxHeight: 20,
                horizontalDragMinWidth: 20,
                horizontalDragMaxWidth: 20
    });
```

the important thing here is the autoreinitialise stuff , and btw i also suggest you add some height to the cointainer of the 2nd scrollpane cause remember the plugin switches the overflow to hidden

```
<div class="scroll-pane" style="height:someheight">
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set a height. It fills the height automatically, so you do not waste any space.